# How to use Hive functionalities in Apache Spark without having an existing Hive Setup?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I'm currently testing the framework of apache spark and i just want to test it locally. It's stated in the apache spark framework documentation that Spark support Hive queries without actually setting it up. Here the Apache Spark documentation states the following:

> `SparkSession` in Spark 2.0 provides builtin support for Hive features
>   including the ability to write queries using HiveQL, access to Hive
>   UDFs, and the ability to read data from Hive tables. To use these
>   features, you do not need to have an existing Hive setup.

How does one actually use these functionalities without actually setting any Hive Setups? A programmatic example would help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: So you just need to add [spark-hive](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.spark%7Cspark-hive_2.11%7C2.1.0%7Cjar) dependency to your build tool, and just add [hive support](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) to your sparkSession: 
`val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()`
No hive installation needed

Comment: what do i specify with in the warehouseLocation? And does the warehouseLocation contain any files inside it?

Comment: _warehouseLocation points to the default location for managed databases and tables._ - it's just a folder where local hive would store temporary tables and metadata.